# form different on windows xp than 7

Tags: forms, windows-7, windows-xp, ms-access-2010

When I converted the access 97 database to 2010, I updated the design of the forms.

Now 1 user told me that the changes give her an instant headache.

**Old form**

[image]

**New one**

[image]

I can't figure out what could cause this cause I don't thing the black font on dark green was better. I also changed the font to `Arial 9` instead of `Ms sans serif 8`

She said it's a little better on my computer than her.
So I changed her monitor for a better one cause she had a really old one but she still find it hard to read.
The only difference now is that she's in `Windows XP` and mine is `Windows 7`

She can't tell what's wrong. She finds that there's a *shadow* on the text

But she said that she didn't have this problem with the old form.

Is there any difference for the font between `Windows XP` and `Windows 7`?

If not, what's wrong with my new design?

Thank you

(If StackOverflow is not the good place to ask, please leave a comment with the proper stackexchange website)

Comment: That shadow text complaint makes me wonder whether a Windows setting for ClearType or something similar may be involved somehow, but I don't really have any better clue.  What prevents you from solving the problem by reverting to the original colors and text attributes?

Comment: @hansup Can you write this as an answer plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complaint about "shadow text" makes me wonder whether a Windows setting for ClearType or something similar may be involved here.  Unfortunately that is only a WAG and I can't offer a better clue.

If it were me, I would be tempted to solve the problem by reverting to the original colors and text attributes.

Comment: I think it's only the light in her office or something like that cause I showed her the old forms and she has the same problem. She uses that application everyday, so I don't know why she started having this problem when I did the update. Thank you

Comment: Aha!  You made changes. She reported trouble due to your changes.  But turned out she had the same trouble with the unchanged original version.  Users!  Ya gotta love em!  :-)